# estimating density in a multidimensional space with R

Tags: r, spatial, multidimensional-array

I have two types of individuals, say M and F, each described with six variables (forming a 6D space S). I would like to identify the regions in S where the densities of M and F differ maximally. I first tried a logistic binomial model linking F/ M to the six variables but the result of this GLM model is very hard to interpret (in part due to the numerous significant interaction terms). Thus I am thinking to an “spatial” analysis where I would separately estimate the density of M and F individuals everywhere in S, then calculating the difference in densities. Eventually I would manually look for the largest difference in densities, and extract the values at the 6 variables.

I found the function sm.density in the package sm that can estimate densities in a 3d space, but I find nothing for a space with n>3.  Would you know something that would manage to do this in R? Alternatively, would have a more elegant method to answer my first question (2nd sentence)?

In advance, 
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The `denpro` package, which focuses on the visualization of multi-dimensional densities, also provides functions to estimate them (on a grid, apparently).

Answer (score 3):

The function `kde` of the package [`ks`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/ks.pdf) performs kernel density estimation for multinomial data with dimensions ranging from 1 to 6.

[`pdfCluster`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdfCluster/pdfCluster.pdf) and [`np`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/np/np.pdf) packages propose functions to perform kernel density estimation in higher dimension.

If you prefer parametric techniques, you look at R packages doing gaussian mixture estimation like [`mclust`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/mclust.pdf) or [`mixtools`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/mixtools.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The ability to do this with GLM models may be constrained both by interpretablity issues that you already encountered as well as by numerical stability issues.  Furthermore, you don't describe the GLM models, so it's not possible to see whether you include consideration of non-linearity. If you have lots of data, you might consider using 2D crossed spline terms. (These are *not* really density estimates.)  If I were doing initial exploration with facilities in the rms/Hmisc packages in five dimensions it might look like:

```
  library(rms)
  dd <- datadist(dat)
  options(datadist="dd")

  big.mod <- lrm( MF ~ ( rcs(var1, 3) +    # `lrm` is logistic regression in rms
                         rcs(var2, 3) +
                         rcs(var3, 3) +
                         rcs(var4, 3) +
                         rcs(var5, 3) )^2,# all 2way interactions
                    data=dat,
                    max.iter=50) # these fits may take longer times
   bplot( Predict(bid.mod, var1,var2, n=10) )
```

That should show the simultaneous functional form of var1's and var2's contribution to the "5 dimensional" model estimates at 10 points each and at the median value of the three other variables.